# jQuery: $.ajax() won't fire or no response from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I've just started learning jQuery and PHP, and I encountered a problem when I try to use Ajax. Either the $.ajax() function won't fire, or PHP won't return anything, I cannot tell. I must have forgotten something really stupid, I guess...

Here's the code. There's no reply, no alert, nothing.

js:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "get_profile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    done: function(response) {
        alert("response");
    }
});

 });
 </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo "Something"; ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firefox->firebug->net panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_profile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    done: function(response) {
        alert("response");
    }
});
```

supposed to be

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_profile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},

}).done(function(response) {
        alert("response");
});
```

`success` , `error` methods are generally declared in the place where you have written `done` which are now deprecated

Comment: Ah, it seems I messed the syntax up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Glastium.. Happens once in a while :)

Answer (score 3):

You have your `done` in the wrong place.

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_profile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {}
})
.done(function(response) {
        alert("response");
});
```

Comment: Ah, it seems I messed the syntax up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have alternative option for check is there any error in your ajax call. and you can  also do some stuff before getting the response of your ajax call like loading image shows to end users until the response result. for this you can use following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_profile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function(){
        //do something like loading image
    },
    success:function(response){
        alert(response);
    },
    error:function(e){
        alert("something wrong"+e);
    }
})
```